How to optimize an Eventbrite listing for faster loading times?
I make events and one of the things I noticed Eventbrite doing is it inflates my image size.
I made a PNG that is 256 color and it only takes up 9K. When I uploaded it to Eventbrite as my organizer profile picture, Eventbrite loads it as a 40K jpeg. I know this because I use the web developer tools in my browser.
Is there a way to strictly enforce Eventbrite to use smaller image sizes without shrinking the picture before upload?

1. Have you tried uploading a JPEG instead of a PNG? 2. What are the dimensions (px) of the image before and after? 3. Why does this small size change matter to you; what is the problem?

yes I tried both. My image dimensions are 940x470px and eventbrite resizes it depending on the client device. The change matters because when I create a png its only 7K in size but eventbrite inflates it to over 40K in size. It takes more time and data to load 40K than it does 7K. If those sizes don't scare you, then try those sizes in megabytes. Also, many people these days are impatient and expect things fast.

You answered 1, didn't answer 2 and for 3 I'm not sure what you are communicating with ""then try those sizes in megabytes" what is the relevance?  There are no MB sizes referenced in your question.  Have "you" tried MB sizes?   Perhaps their image manipulation has some consistent overhead that becomes irrelevant once the file sizes start to become relevant.  Your question would benefit from additional data and examples images (before/after). Do the png characteristics change?  Perhaps they use a different file type.
